# How do I save the positions and sizes of all current programs and restore them later?

Tags: windows-7

In Windows 7, is there a way to save the position and size of each program currently open, and then later restore this configuration by opening each program in the same position and size as before?

Comment: Not without using third-party software.  Is that okay?

Comment: Yes. Do you know of anything?

Comment: Not offhand, but the way you worded the question left it unclear if you wanted something built-in to the operating system or not, hence the request for clarification.  Hopefully somebody else will know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of searching, I ran across this program:

http://www.desksoft.com/WindowManager.htm

It seems to do what you are asking, but is costs $10 (free trial available). I have not tried it myself, but the forums I stumbled across lead me to believe that it works.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I suggest [WinSize2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/winsize2/). It is my preferred one.
It basically stores (via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> hotkey pressing) the **position and dimensions** of the desired window(s) for the next time it is open:

[image: WinSize2 ScreenShot]

- Move windows automatically to a predefined place.
- Resize width and/or height.
- Moving OR changing size possible.
- Supports text CONTAINED in titles (like "Notepad") to identify windows.
- One hotkey for all functions.
- Multi language support.
- Handbook:English and Denmark.

Tested working on Windows XP SP3 and Windows 7 SP1. Will probably work on most Windows.